# boost filesystem - How to get last write time for symlink without resolving?

Tags: c++, boost, stat, boost-filesystem

Suppose we have 2 files:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... 3 Jun  8 09:42 d3 -> dir
d--------- 3 ... 80 Jun  9 16:14 dir
```

One is a symlink to a directory, and another is the actual directory.

When I write

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
std::cout << "last write time for symlink : " << 
    fs::last_write_time("x/d3") << " and the actual dir : " <<
    fs::last_write_time("x/dir") << std::endl;
```

I get back:

```
last write time for symlink : 1528578878 and the actual dir : 1528578878
```

This means the `last_write_time` is resolving my path that I'm inputting. How do I use `boost::filesystem` to get the actual statistics?

If not, then I think I'll have to resort to `lstat`'ing the symlink which is fine, but a little smelly having to move from modern c++ to low level c syscalls.

Here's an example of the `lstat` solution(todo: obviously throw a better exception):

```
std::time_t last_write_time(const fs::path& p){
    struct stat s;
    if(lstat(p.c_str(), &s) == -1)
        throw "last_write_time failed.";
    return s.st_mtime;
}
```

Comment: boost::filesystem has to be more generic than your symlink capable filesystem. IMHO this is a very reasonable behavior.

Comment: I understand that it has to be more generic, as it is portable across filesystems that do not support symlinks. However, for it to be powerful enough to be used in specific filesystems that do support it(i.e. most of linux flavors), it should expose api that does not make the user go back to using low level C.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we can see from [`operations.cpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/5a93351bfdf859ee47245e0429739226767ef0d7/src/operations.cpp) that the only `lstat()` call in Boost Filesystem is in `symlink_status()`, which returns only the file type and permissions, not timestamps.

So you're out of luck for now, but you could try submitting a patch, as clearly Boost Filesystem is not averse to using `lstat()`.

Comment: Argh! The same is true for C++17 std::filesystem. Nasty!